# Why don't RedHat 5.x compiled Ruby-binaries work on Fedora 17?

Tags: redhat, fedora, ruby

I have compiled Ruby 2.0.0p247-binaries on a RedHat Enterprise Linux 5-system. When I `require 'net/https'` on this same system, everything is fine.

The binaries have been installed on a common application repository however and when I try to execute the same command from a Fedora Core 17-system, Ruby fails with the following error message:

```
LoadError: libssl.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /apps/ruby/2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so
```

When I `ls` the directory it's complaining about, the file is there (and it loads properly on the RedHat-system). Are RedHat-compiled binaries incompatible with Fedora? Apart from installing Ruby to a separate location specific to the Fedora-system, would there be any other solutions?

Comment: RHEL 5 is _much older_ than Fedora 17 (which is EOL and you should update it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seem obvious that the RHEL 5.x (you did not specify the specific version) compiled binaries do not work on Fedora 17 due to package version incompatibility...although specifically libssl, there might be other supporting libraries/programs will be incompatible also...the one you mentioned is the only one flagged.

In general, unless you have the basically the same type of underlying package configuration, binaries created on one OS distribution do NOT necessarily work on another OS distribution.